# Linux server mount uknown filesystem type

Tags: linux, ssh

i broke ssh on my server, and i am running recovery, and I need to mount my largest hard disk, to do so I am executing this command:

```
root@grml ~ # mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
```

But i am getting this error
mount: unknown filesystem type `linux_raid_member`

Do you know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This errors means that your `/dev/sdb3` is a partition that should be used by `mdadm`. You may be missing disks, or you'll find what you look for in some `/dev/mdX` device.

Are you sure this is the partition you meant to mount?